# Powershell Output to a csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have got this script and it works very well, how can i make it write the output to a csv file?

```
Get-AzureADApplication -All:$true | Select-Object AppId, displayName -ExpandProperty PasswordCredentials | Where-Object EndDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(100) | Sort-Object EndDate | Format-Table AppId, DisplayName, EndDate
```

This what i have tried:

```
Get-AzureADApplication -All:$true | Select-Object AppId, displayName -ExpandProperty PasswordCredentials | Where-Object EndDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(100) | Sort-Object EndDate | Format-Table AppId, DisplayName, EndDate | Export-CSV C:\Users\username\Test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

But I get an error -

> Export-Csv: Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'C' does not
> exist.

Comment: Where are you running this from, the Azure portal? Also, never pipe `Format-Table` to anything. If you want to capture the results in a variable, or output it to a CSV use `Select-Object` if you need to specify specific properties, or just remove it entirely.

Comment: Instead of using Format-Table replace with Export-Csv -path 'path' -NoTypeInformation

Answer (score -1):

Yes sometimes PowerShell chokes on file paths as a string in certain cases it can't seem to handle the \ character.

The best idea I have is to add an extra variable that creates an actual path object using Convert-Path or Join-Path experiment with the help for both of those CMDLETs and see if one of those may be able to help you get past this error.

Some other considerations are to wrap your path in single quotes but based on your sudo path you provided I imaging you are replacing the actual users name with a variable, in that case the single quote "trick" would not probably work well, because you need the double quote to have it properly expand that variable and not take it as a literal string. I will stop rambling now but you have found one of the PowerShell annoyances.

Comment: ``\`` has no special meaning _to PowerShell_. Thus, from _inside a PowerShell session_, a path such as `C:\Users\username\Test.csv` is passed _verbatim_ to a target command, including `Export-Csv` - even if unquoted, and even if `username` is replaced with a variable reference.